# Непонятная ошибка с шаблонами

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Необходимо создать несколько классов контейнеров. Общие функции я решил вынести в базовый класс `Base`. Также необходима возможность конвертирования от одного типа содержащегося объекта к другому, я решил это сделать с помощью copy-initialization. Код:

```
template <typename TObj, template<typename T> class TDerived>
class Base
{
    public:
    Base(TObj *o)
    {
    }
    template<typename TAnotherObj>
    TDerived<TAnotherObj> cast()
    {
        //stub
        return TDerived<TAnotherObj>(0);
    }
};

template <typename TObj>
class Container: public Base<TObj, Container>
{
    public:
    Container(TObj *o):Base<TObj, Container>(o){}

    template<typename TAnotherObj>
    Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base<TObj, Container>(container2.cast<TObj>())
    {       
    }
};

class Obj1{};

class Obj2{};

int main(){
    Container<Obj1> container1(new Obj1());
    (Container<Obj2>) container1;
}
```

Однако возникает непонятная ошибка:

```
In constructor «Container<TObj>::Container(Container<TAnotherObj>)»:
ошибка: expected primary-expression before «>» token
Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base<TObj, Container>(container2.cast<TObj>())

ошибка: expected primary-expression before «)» token
Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base<TObj, Container>(container2.cast<TObj>())
```

Если убрать `<TObj>`, то есть оставить просто `container2.cast()`, то будет другая ошибка:

```
ошибка: нет подходящей функции для вызова «Container<Obj1>::cast()»
  Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base<TObj, Container>(container2.cast())

замечание: candidate is:
замечание: template<class TAnotherObj> TDerived<TAnotherObj> Base<TObj, TDerived>::cast() [with TAnotherObj = TAnotherObj; TObj = Obj1; TDerived = Container]
  TDerived<TAnotherObj> cast()

замечание:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
замечание:   couldn't deduce template parameter «TAnotherObj»
  Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base<TObj, Container>(container2.cast())
```

Почему возникают ошибки и как их исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы нужно было добавить `template` перед `cast`:

```
template<typename TAnotherObj>
Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):
    Base<TObj, Container>(container2.template cast<TObj>()){}
```

Почему так — я сам не очень понял, но примерно можно объяснить так: `cast` — это «зависимое» имя (зависит от параметров шаблона), поэтому компилятору нужно сказать, что это шаблон метода (а, например, не переменная). В общем, как говорится, «в любой непонятной ситуации добавляй template или typename».

Как правильно заметил [[@atwice](/users/12261/atwice)](/users/12261/atwice), в базовом классе конструктор принимает аргумент `TObj*`, а не `Container<TObj>`. Однако код с приведённым выше исправлением все равно работает, наверное, из-за того, что компилятор использует встроенный конструктор копирования.

Comment: А почему Вы используете приведение типов в стиле C?

Comment: @atwice здесь это лишь как пример конвертирования. Вообще, в данном случае, разницы нет: при использовании `static_cast` та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятору станет легче, если Вы уберете в секции инициализации шаблонные параметры класса `Base`. У `Container` ровно один предок, и он знает его точные аргументы шаблона.

```
template <typename TObj>
class Container: public Base<TObj, Container>
{
    public:
    Container(TObj *o):Base(o){}

    template<typename TAnotherObj>
    Container(Container<TAnotherObj> container2):Base(container2.cast<TObj>()) {}
//...
```

А дальше становится очевидной проблема:

```
Base<TObj,Container>::Base(const Base<TObj,Container> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Container<Obj2> *' to 'Obj2 *'
```

То есть Вы пытаетесь вызвать конструктор `Base<TObj>()` с аргументом `container2.cast<TObj>()`. Но результат метода `cast<TObj>` - это `Container<TObj>`, а ожидается тип `TObj*`. Элементарно, не может привести типы.

Вот так будет работать:

```
template <typename TObj, template<typename T> class TDerived>
class Base {
public:
    Base(TObj *o) {}

    template<typename TAnotherObj>
    TAnotherObj* cast2() const
    {
        //stub
        return 0;         // тут изменил тип на содержимое контейнера
    }
};

template <typename TObj>
class Container : public Base<TObj, Container>
{
public:
    Container(TObj *o) :Base(o){}

    template<typename TAnotherObj>
    Container(const Container<TAnotherObj>& container2)
     :  Base( container2.cast2<TObj>()) // тут передаю указатель на содержимое
    {} 
};

// Obj1, Obj2...

int main() {
Container<Obj1> container1( new Obj1() );
//(Container<Obj2>) container1;
Container<Obj2> container2( container1 ); // явно вызываю конструктор "копирования"
}
```

Comment: Мне нужен именно тот код, что вы закомментировали: `(Container<Obj2>) container1`. А с ним те же самые ошибки. Кстати, если убрать шаблонные параметры класса `Base`, то первой ошибкой будет "в классе «Container<TObj>» нет поля с именем «Base»", то есть, по-видимому, они всё-таки нужны.